# Nonlinear model wirh effects over linear term

Tags: r, regression, statistical-significance, nonlinear-regression, mixed-model

I have been working in `R` with nonlinear models such us:

$Y = \alpha_{0}\text{(varia)} + \alpha_{1}\text{Time}\text{(varia)} + \alpha_{2}\sin(\frac{2\pi\text{Time}}{\alpha_{3}}) + \alpha_{4}(-1^{\text{Time}})$

And I would line whether a Bernoulli variable affects to the $\alpha_{1}\text{Time}$ and intercept or not. Such Bernoulli variable could be:

```
varia<-rep("BEFORE","AFTER"),each=30)
```

Using:

```
Y<- -2.5+rnorm(60)+2*sin(2*pi*time/8)+2.5*(-1)^time
time<-seq(1,60)
```

I found that `nls` can fit this model but without the effect of this categorical variable,

I also found that the `nlme` package can estimate effects over variables not over terms of the nonlinear model.

My question is: Which of these package could help me? and, how could I add this Bernoulli variable in the code?

Regards and thanks.

Comment: I have edited your question for readability, grammar, and mathematical notation: I also explicitly added an intercept to your model, since you reference it in the text, but neglected to include it in the model). Also: you mention creating the Bernoulli variable `varia`, but neither your abstract nor code models incorporate it, so it is unclear precisely what you are asking.

Comment: What problem, precisely, do you encounter in fitting this model with `nls`? It certainly can accommodate this model (using the "plinear" algorithm, for instance)--but whether it finds the *best* fit or even a good fit is another matter that depends on the specific data as well as the model itself.

Comment: Even after the improvements it's not completely clear to me what the problem is. nls should be able to fit such a model

Comment: The problem is that I would like to know whether this _bernoulli_ or _dummy_ variable has influence over the linear parameters or not. Perhaps is necessary to use a mixed model using this _bernoulli_ variable as "covariable" (i'm not sure about it).

Answer (score 1):

You can make it an indicator variable, for example:

```
time<- 1:60
Y<- -2.5+rnorm(60)+2*sin(2*pi*time/8)    # +2.5*(-1)^time
jump <- c(rep(1,30), rep(0, 30))
sint <- sin(2*pi*time/8)

lmq <- lm( Y ~ time + jump + sint)
```

I'm writing a linear model here because your model is almost linear (with the exception of Alpha3). Also, the "zigzag" term

```
   +2.5*(-1)^time
```

is really strange.

EDIT: ok you can keep the zigzag term, it doesn't really matter. But the reason to do a linear model is for your equation, the behavior of nls can be really bad. You can just run a sequence of linear models, with varying values of Alpha3, and keep the best one. At least, this will give you a good starting point to use with nls.

Comment: This "zigzag" term is really helpfull for detecting mixtures of populations, even so, it is a linear term. Here, the problem is the period of sinus wave, it is also a parameter to be estimated and can not be used the _lm_ function. The purpose of this question is to compare the model with _jump_ and without _jump_  tnks.

Comment: I've just found the _gnm_ package really helpful, it handles with generalized nonlinear models estimated by MLE, and your proposal helped me to set the starting values in the function. I just added an extra element to the formula and so, evaluated if this _bernoulli_ variable affected the model. However, the problems has not been solved since I want to know the influence only over the linear terms not over the general model.